# ormlite query with multiple tables in where conditions

Tags: java, ormlite

I'd like to do something like this:

```
    Select * from A join B where (A.a=x and B.b=y);
```

I've tried:

```
    qbA = aDao.queryBuilder();
    qbB = bDao.queryBuilder();
    whereA = qbA.where();
    whereB = qbB.where();
    join = qbA.join(qbB);
    whereJ = join.where();
    whereJ.and(whereA.eq(A.a, x), whereB.eq(B.b, y));
```

It gives me compilation error. I have also tried to use only joins where like:

```
    whereJ.and(whereJ.eq(A.a=x), whereJ.eq(B.b=y));
```

I got runtime error: "A doesn't have 'b' attribute".

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can't combine where statements like that.  You should do the following:

```
whereA = qbA.where();
whereA.eq(A.a, x);
whereB = qbB.where();
whereB.eq(B.b, y);
join = qbA.join(qbB);
```

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) should take care of doing the `AND` and putting together the 2 different `WHERE` statements.

Comment: What if we want to do an OR instead of AND while combining the where statements?